# NMDS with species-sites matrix and iterations

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, ecology, vegan

How could I conduct an NMDS-ordination for a species-sites matrix with multiple iterations? I know how to conduct a NMDS with a "normal" species-sites matrix, but I couldn't find any information in the web, how to deal with data, that is more complex. In this case: if you have one more dimension to pass, for example the time of year.

I sampled species in different times of the sampling season to get a picture of the complete community of my choosen sites. So I sampled species that can be found almost the whole season as well as species that can be found only at the beginning / end of the season.

I have three possible solutions, but no real favorite:

1. I could select the maximum abundance of the species per site from the whole season. The problems with this approach are, that I would throw away the information of:

- Phenology of the species (early, late species or whole time of the season)
- Frequency of the species (just once in the whole season or multiple times)

In my opinion, this informations should definitely be included in the ordination, because the more information is given to the ordination, the more information can be taken into account and then presented accordingly. Or am I wrong?

2. Let the ordination be calculated per iteration. But then I have six unrelated calculations, which again do not include the information about the frequency of the species, because they have been calculated individually and incoherently.
3. With all the data together (for example: 20 sites x 5 iterations = 100 lines of data) let calculate the ordination. Here I find no possibility to say, that the 6 entries per test section belong together and therefore represent one picture over time.

If possible I would like to conduct the NMDS in the vegan package and/or R.

EDIT:
I sampled Odonata (dragonflies/damselflies) at river-sections in middle-europe. So the season starts in april and ends in september. The sampled sections belong to different rivers. So in total I have 25 sections from five rivers.

My aim was to let the ordination(NMDS) calculate an order/arrangement based on the abundances of the species. Subsequently I want to check if the arranged sites show any grouping by add a color or hull based on variables of the sites/rivers on the plot like [here](https://chrischizinski.github.io/figs/2014-04-13-vegan-ggplot2/unnamed-chunk-10.png).

Comment: Could you please add information about your study (e.g. species, sampling method, number of sites, etc.) and specify the aims of your analyses? I think it would help to decide which option is the best.